# react native cannot get appended data in server side

Tags: node.js, react-native, fetch, multipartform-data

I want to upload image to the database. However, when I use fetch method with 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' but I cannot get the appended data in the server side. It shows that I have no data in the body.

Below is fetching part of the coding

```
editProfile = () => {
    let bodyData = new FormData();

    let photo={
        uri:this.state.uri,
        type:this.state.type,
        fileName:this.state.fileName,
    }

    bodyData.append('transactionCode', 'UPDATEPROFILE');
    // bodyData.append('photo', photo);

    console.log(bodyData);

    fetch(URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        body: bodyData,
    }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            alert(responseJson);
        })
        .catch((error) => {

            alert(error);
        });
}
```

This is the example of how i check the data at the server side

```
const custfunction = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
}
```

When i console.log(req), it shows body:{} is empty

Comment: If you are using express as a backend, just add "app.use(express.bodyParser());"

Comment: Yes, I do have the bodyParser as below but it still does not work
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '200mb', extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '200mb', extended: true }));

Comment: Alright, I just find out the problem. I need to use Multer to handle multipart/form-data in the backend. Thanks a lot.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I just find out the problem. I need to use Multer to handle multipart/form-data in the backend. Thanks a lot.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer